# Nltk .most_common(), what is the order it is returned in?

Tags: nltk, n-gram, frequency-analysis, human-language

I have found the frequecny of bigrams in certain sentences using:

```
import nltk 
from nltk import ngrams
mydata = “xxxxx"
mylist = mydata.split()
mybigrams =list(ngrams(mylist, 2))
fd = nltk.FreqDist(mybigrams)
print(fd.most_common())
```

On printing out the bigrams with the most common frequencies, one occurs 7 times wheras all 95 other bigrams only occur 1 time. However when comparing the bigrams to my sentences I can see no logical order to the way the bigrams all of frequency 1 are printed out. Does anyone know if there is any logic to the way .most_common() prints the bigrams or is it randomly generated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, based on the documentation of [collections.Counter.most_common](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

> Elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily:

In current versions of NLTK, `nltk.FreqDist` is based on `nltk.compat.Counter`. On Python 2.7 and 3.x, `collections.Counter` will be imported from the standard library. On Python 2.6, NLTK provides its own implementation.

For details, look at the source code:
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/compat.py

In conclusion, without checking all possible version configurations, you cannot expect words with equal frequency to be ordered.